# Missing session values while creating PDF file using html2fpdf script

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I am creating HTML to PDF using html2fpdf script, I am not able to write session value in that.

I am not getting session value in PDF file.

Comment: This is missing a [mcve] so should be put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provided any sample code, I guess most probably you have forgotten session_start(), at the beginning of your php file.

Then make sure the session var you want to read is set on the same domain. See, http://domain.tld and http://www.domain.tld - are not the same! 
Even they show the same website, if you set a session var on http://domain.tld/test.php and try to display it on http://www.domain.tld/test.php , it won't work!

And then, after you make sure you can display the var, then you should be able to print it in your pdf.

Comment: I have already put session_start at the beginning of the file but still it is not working..

Comment: Ya sure. I have alaredy user Id in session. The code is like that "session_start(); then I used to echo $_SESSION['user_id'];. But It is not working.